# Can the algorithm used in Google Maps be overriden?

Tags: google-maps

i am currently trying to implement ant colony optimization in vehicle routing problem. what i have in mind is to have an application using the google maps since it has a library that would lessen my burden, and not to start from scratch.

my current problem now is actually if the algorithm in the google maps implementation in finding the path from an origin to a destination point can be overriden.

thank you for your understanding and any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Yes, it can be overridden, if you can access Google's servers that is. :-)

Comment: thanks. how to access google servers? i mean, i am trying to create an app using another algorithm. how to do this?

Comment: I guess the comment of Marcelo  was more hypothetically. When the algorithm did not meet your requirements, you may use a custom function instead of requesting the directionsService, this should  be possible.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do that the Googles Direction Service doesn't provide?It provides the shortage route between 2 locations.If you want to show how the "ant trail" is generated you will need to provide your own code. You can use the map to show each path and how it develops. But it will require a lot of effort